# Export and then Import VMs on Windows 8, missing config file

Tags: windows-8, export, import, hyper-v

I have a VM that was exported from Server 2008. It uses the `.VHD` format, not `.VHDX` . The exported folder has a `config.xml` file in the root.
I have imported this VM in Win8 just fine, tweaked it and Exported it again.

But when I now move this Export to another Win8 machine it cannot be Imported: "No Virtual machines found".

I know the right folder and I have tried a few levels up and down to be sure.

Looking at my Export it still uses .VHD files but there is no `config.xml`

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: just copy the `config.xml` from the original export to the newly exported folder.